# Issue for import-csv and foreach

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to import a csv, then delete from AD several objects

```
$ImportComputer = "C:\Users\deng\Desktop\ComputerLastlogondateformatBis.csv"

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

foreach ($Computer in(Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\deng\Desktop\ComputerLastlogondateformatBis.csv))
{
Remove-ADObject -Identity $Computer.'Computer'
```

these two object exist in AD, but I cannot seem to find out why it is not working.

see below error message:

```
Remove-ADObject : Cannot find an object with identity: 'fr-borr-mac' under: 'DC=PII,DC=net'.
At C:\Users\deng\OneDrive - Aptus Health\Script\Export.ps1:7 char:1
+ Remove-ADObject -Identity $Computer.'Computer'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (fr-borr-mac:ADObject) [Remove-ADObject], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADObject

Remove-ADObject : Cannot find an object with identity: 'jlinmacfr' under: 'DC=PII,DC=net'.
At C:\Users\deng\OneDrive - Aptus Health\Script\Export.ps1:7 char:1
+ Remove-ADObject -Identity $Computer.'Computer'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Content of the CSV below:

```
Computer   
--------   
fr-borr-mac
jlinmacfr
```

Could anyone give input on this?

Comment: Computer   
--------   
fr-borr-mac => one line per object
jlinmacfr => one line per object

Comment: Can you please format your code as code so it is more readable

Comment: why not use `Remove-ADComputer` instead?

Comment: @Nicicalu foreach ($Computer in(Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\deng\Desktop\ComputerLastlogondateformatBis.csv)) { Remove-ADObject -Identity $Computer.'Computer'}

Comment: @DavidNg https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @AdminOfThings it worked all i had to do is to repace by Remove-ADComputer

Answer (score 0):

The `-Identity` parameter on the `*-ADObject` commands expect either a `DistinguishedName` or `Guid` value. If you are wanting to work with `SamAccountName` or some other attribute, you should consider using the `*-ADComputer` or using `-Filter` to find your objects.

```
# Using Remove-ADObject
Remove-ADObject -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($Computer.Computer)'"

# Using Remove-ADComputer
Remove-ADComputer -Identity $Computer.Computer
```

Alternatively, you can use `Get-ADComputer` or `Get-ADObject` to retrieve your object first and then pipe that into `Remove-ADObject`.

```
Get-ADObject -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($Computer.Computer)'" | Remove-ADObject
```

---

See the [Remove-ADObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/remove-adobject?view=win10-ps) documentation for the following excerpt regarding explicitly binding to `-Identity`:

> Specifies an Active Directory object by providing one of the following
>   property values. The identifier in parentheses is the Lightweight
>   Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) display name for the attribute. The
>   acceptable values for this parameter are:
>
> - A distinguished name
> - A GUID (objectGUID)

For piping an object into `Remove-ADObject`, the following excerpt applies, which is why you can use a `Get-AD*` command and pipe the result into the `Remove-ADObject`:

> This parameter can also get this object through the pipeline or you
>   can set this parameter to an object instance.
>
> Derived types, such as the following, are also accepted:
>
> - Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup
> - Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser
> - Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer
> - Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADServiceAccount
> - Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFineGrainedPasswordPolicy
> - Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADDomain